# Oracle SQL Developer, whose name (PRODUCT_NAME) does not contain the symbols '_' and '<'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table product_information with columns: product_id, product_name and product_description.I want to make a query  (PRODUCT_NAME) does not contain the symbols '_' and '<'.
Can you help me ?

I try:

```
 select * from product_information 
WHERE product_name NOT LIKE '%[_[<]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `instr` function:

```
SQL> with product_information (product_id, product_name) as
  2    (select 1, 'Toyota_Aygo'      from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'BMW < Audi'       from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Mercedes'         from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Up < Polo < Golf' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Citroen_C3_C4'    from dual
  7    )
  8  select *
  9  from product_information
 10  where instr(product_name, '_') = 0
 11    and instr(product_name, '<') = 0;

PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- ----------------
         3 Mercedes

SQL>
```

Or, regular expressions:

```
  8  select *
  9  from product_information
 10  where not regexp_like(product_name, '_|<');

PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- ----------------
         3 Mercedes

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

select * from product_information
WHERE product_name NOT LIKE '%_%' AND product_name NOT LIKE '%<%'

Comment: try above suggestion

Comment: That won't work because the underscore wildcard specifies a single position in which any character can occur, so condition you used `%_%` is as if you used just `%`, i.e. it won't filter underscores. It would work if you escaped it, e.g. `product_name not like '%\_%' escape '\'`.